# Save user input to paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a program where the user will input some text in a field and when pressing "Start" the text will go to a paragraph but it will be shown backwards.
Trying to do this with Html,jquery and Css.
How can I do this?

Here's the Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="head">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="BackTalk.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BackTalk.css">
    <title>BackTalk</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <div id="Main">
        <form>
            <input id="input" type="number" value="Start">
            <button id="input2"  onclick="">Start</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <form id="frm">
        <p id="para"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the $/javascript (Main part I need help with as you can see):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#input2').click(function () {
    });
});
```

Css (Don't know if needed):

```
#head {
}

#body {
    background-image: url('stardust.png');
}

#Main {
    width: 230px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px double #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: auto;
}

#frm {
    width: 230px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px double #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: auto;
}

#input {
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#input2 {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: what parts of this are you having trouble with? It's a very simple task..

Comment: `$('#para').text( $('#input').val().split('').reverse().join('') );`

Comment: @judgeja well, I am a beginner at this. I guess that's why.

Comment: By backwards what do you mean exactly ?? do you want to show your para content behind the textbox ?

Comment: @Tushar Raj  I mean that the characters should come out backwards in the paragraph when clicking start.
For example:
User Input: "Hey".
Comes out like this:
"yeH"

Comment: @BellcrossAndersson I know, but what exact bit is the trouble because each step is easily searchable, even though it can be daunting to find where to start as a beginner it's something you'll learn :). You need to use javascript (or jquery) to: 1)Read from an input. 2)Reverse a string. 3)Write the reversed string to an paragraph.

Comment: check if my fiddle works out for you and your textbox accepts only number type as i can see ..so it will reverse the numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/th778nfs/

```
 $('#input2').click(function () {
  var value=$('#input').val();
  console.log($('#para').text(value.split("").reverse().join("")));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#startbutton').click(function () {
        $('#para').text($('#input').val().split('').reverse().join(''));
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwa5x170/1/)